# To get process age or elapsed time in linux from ps command

Tags: linux, ps

i also want elapsed time in below output.Since how many hour loader.pl job is running.

```
[etl@etl3(8) ~]$ ps -ef | grep loader.pl
etl      573398      1  2 07:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl -w              /opt/etl/pm_samsung_lte_csl//bin/csls-loader.pl --task etl3.gphd.local-1
etl      574203 324544  0 07:36 pts/9    00:00:00 grep --color loader.pl
```

but when i am running command like below to get all the process elapsed time..i didn't get the loder.pl process id itself

```
[etl@etl3(8) ~]$ ps -eo pid,etime,comm
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
PID     ELAPSED COMMAND
324544    02:12:51 bash
574205       00:05  \_ bash
574206       00:05  |   \_ logger
574345       00:01  \_ ps
[etl@etl3(8) ~]$
```

i am not getting desired loader.pl process id's

Comment: `bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'` is an error. Do you really input `minus` here, not an _em dash_ or _en dash_ (happens when you're copying from bad blog platforms)

Comment: no its minus only

Answer (score 0):

You should get the exactly process ID you want to check firstly, and then use this command:
ps -p  -o lstart,etime

In my example, I want to check PID 23210,

$ ps -p 23210 -o lstart,etime
                 STARTED     ELAPSED
Tue Oct 10 10:25:23 2017  5-17:21:43

Comment: Hello Jesson thank you...i could find this...but i want to check the elapsed time of all the process in one go...not one by one